# Need help indenting tags in the output in Ruby

Tags: ruby

UPDATE: OK, so I implemented your code, but now the indentation is not showing up! Any ideas what might be wrong? I modified the code so that it would attempt to pass my original test (this is only an exercise so in real life I would not be overriding the XmlDocument class) and here is the modified code:

```
class XmlDocument

attr_reader :indent_depth, :bool

def initialize(bool = false, indent_depth = 0)
    @indent_depth = indent_depth
    @bool = bool
end

def method_missing(name, *args)
    indentation = '  '*indent_depth
    attrs = (args[0] || {}).map { |k, v| " #{k}='#{v}'" }.join(' ')
    if block_given?
        puts indent_depth
        opening = "#{indentation}<#{name}#{attrs}>"
        contents = yield(XmlDocument.new(true,indent_depth+1))
        closing = "#{indentation}</#{name}>"
        bool ? opening + "\n" + contents + "\n" + closing : opening + contents + closing
    else
        "#{indentation}<#{name}#{attrs}/>"
    end
end
end
```

I'm trying to get the method to pass this test:

```
it "indents" do
@xml = XmlDocument.new(true)
@xml.hello do
  @xml.goodbye do
    @xml.come_back do
      @xml.ok_fine(:be => "that_way")
    end
  end
end.should ==
"<hello>\n" +
"  <goodbye>\n" +
"    <come_back>\n" +
"      <ok_fine be='that_way'/>\n" +
"    </come_back>\n" +
"  </goodbye>\n" +
"</hello>\n"
```

...but I'm unsure as to where to go with my code, below. I was thinking of using a counter to keep track of how far indented we have to go. I tried some code, but then deleted it because it was getting too messy and I have a feeling that the indentation should not be too complicated to implement.

```
class XmlDocument

    def initialize(bool = false)
        @bool = bool
    end

    def send(tag_name)
        "<#{tag_name}/>"
    end

    def method_missing(meth, arg={}, &block)

        arbitrary_method = meth.to_s
        tag_string = ''

        # 1) test for block
        # 2) test for arguments
        # 3) test for hash
        if block_given? # check for @xml.hello do; @xml.goodbye; end
            if yield.class == String # base case: @xml.hello do; "yellow"; end
                "<#{arbitrary_method}>#{yield}</#{arbitrary_method}>"
            else # in the block we do not have a string, we may have another method
                method_missing(yield)
            end
        elsif arg.empty? # no arguments e.g. @xml.hello
            send(arbitrary_method)
        else # hash as argument e.g. @xml.hello(:name => 'dolly')
            send("#{arbitrary_method} #{arg.keys[0]}='#{arg.values[0]}'")
        end


    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs a lot of work - some pointers:

- *Do not* override the `send` method!
- Don't call `yield` over and over - you don't know what side effects you might cause, not to mention a performance hit - call it once, and remember the return value.
- You might want to read up on how to write a DSL ([here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/writing-a-domain-specific-language-in-ruby) is a blogpost on the subject), to see how it was done correctly in other places.

Ignoring the above, I will try to answer your question regarding indentation.

In a DSL use case, you might want to use a context object which holds the indentation depth as state:

```
class Indented
  attr_reader :indent_depth
  def initialize(indent_depth = 0)
    @indent_depth = indent_depth
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    indentation = '  '  * indent_depth
    attrs = (args[0] || {}).map { |k, v| "#{k}='#{v}'" }.join(' ')
    if block_given?
      "#{indentation}<#{name} #{attrs}>\n" + 
        yield(Indented.new(indent_depth + 1)) + 
      "\n#{indentation}</#{name}>"
    else

      "#{indentation}<#{name} #{attrs}/>"
    end
  end
end

xml = Indented.new
puts xml.hello do |x|
  x.goodbye do |x|
    x.come_back do |x|
      x.ok_fine(:be => "that_way")
    end
  end
end    
# => <hello >
# =>   <goodbye >
# =>     <come_back >
# =>       <ok_fine be='that_way'/>
# =>     </come_back>
# =>   </goodbye>
# => </hello>
```

Comment: Thanks man, this really helped! However, is it possible to initialize the object with only a boolean, like in the original test, and somehow keep track of the indent depth?

Comment: Actually, I guess I can add an optional argument of indent depth in the initialization!

Comment: I implemented your code, but now the indentation won't show up for some reason (I edited the original question).

Comment: @jyim - 1) don't change the question in a way that will void the answers. 2) check your usage - see the example in my code - I use the passed parameter (`x`) not the main variable (`xml`)